# Printing the value of a char array

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to write a function that takes in a `const char*` and iterates through it until it matches the first character of the `const char* hello`. It then prints the amount of characters it had to advance and the `mth` character. As of now, I have gotten it to point to where I want to, but I can't seem to access it

```
const char* hello = "hello";
const char* no_bears = "ERROR:  Message must contain 'THIS IS BEAR TERRITORY!' yeeee";

int is_commit_msg_ok(const char* msg) {
  /* COMPLETE THE REST */
  int m = 0;
  char* message = &msg[0];
  while (message[m] != hello[0]) {
    if (message[m] == '\0') {
        return 0;
    }
    m++;

  }
  printf("%d\n",m );
  printf("%s\n", message[m]); \\ causes segmentation fault
```

When I do message[m], however, I get a segementation fault: 11 error, and I don't really know how to fix this...

Comment: What's the value of `m` at the point of the fault, and how large a buffer is `message`?

Comment: `'/0'` should be `'\0'`. Is that a copying error or in the actual code?

Comment: if i put "abcdh" then the value of m at the moment of segmentation is 5. "ah" it is 2,

Comment: oh. whoops. it was actual code. I'll fix that

Comment: If that is actual code, what about the comments with `\\\`? that will not compile!

Comment: (1) post actual code, (2) pay attention to compiler errors/warnings

Comment: @M.M This is indeed my actual code. Yes, it compiles. If it isn't supposed to I don't know how it did. May it be the script my Machine Structures professor provided for us to compile? I don't know. The only error the compiler was giving me was the segmentation fault.

Comment: `char* message = &msg[0];` is an error because you dropped the `const`. It'd be helpful to figure out how to invoke your compiler in conforming mode, you will get a lot more help out of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line:

```
printf("%s\n", message[m]);
```

`message` is of type `char*` so `message[m]` is of type `char` but `%s` expects a `char*`.

Passing the wrong type to `printf()` is *undefined behaviour*. But what it probably does is to interpret the `char` value as a pointer and try to read the memory there. Since it is not a valid pointer, it segmentation-faults.

Solution, use `%c`, that prints a `char`.

```
printf("%c\n", message[m]);
```

Many modern compilers will warn you about these kind of errors if you enable the warnings. For example in GCC/Clang, you should really use `-Wall`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `printf("%s\n", message +m);` to print the end of the string starting at m.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: Yes, or equivalently `printf("%s\n", &message[m]);`.

Comment: You guys are amazing. Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `printf("%c\n", message[m]);` because you printing just single char not a string with "*%s*".